# Split express node js into two

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, export

I'm trying to split a code to two using express.
Here is what it I did

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var stud = require('./grades');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

stud.excellence;

app.listen(port);
```

grades.js

```
var text = '{ "students" : [' +
'{ "name":"Elsa" , "grade":"70" , "course":"ws" , "year":"2015" },' +
'{ "name":"Anna" , "grade":"80" , "course":"ws" , "year":"2016" },' +
'{ "name":"Anna" , "grade":"86" , "course":"math" , "year":"2014" },' +
'{ "name":"Ron" , "grade":"92" , "course":"math" , "year":"2016" } ]}';


module.exports = function excellence() {
    app.get('/getAllExcellenceStudent', function(req, res) {
        res.json(text);

    })

};
```

When I'm trying to run it in my loclhost writing http://localhost:3000/getAllExcellenceStudent I get Cannot GET /getAllExcellenceStudent

What did I do wrong?

Comment: try to remove the line `module.exports = function excellence() {`

Answer (score 0):

Your app.js should be like this. Actually you are missing app.use() to define routes

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var stud = require('./grades');

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use('/students', stud);

app.listen(port);
```

Your grades.js file should be like this.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var text = '{ "students" : [' +
    '{ "name":"Elsa" , "grade":"70" , "course":"ws" , "year":"2015" },' +
    '{ "name":"Anna" , "grade":"80" , "course":"ws" , "year":"2016" },' +
    '{ "name":"Anna" , "grade":"86" , "course":"math" , "year":"2014" },' +
    '{ "name":"Ron" , "grade":"92" , "course":"math" , "year":"2016" } ]}';



        router.get('/getAllExcellenceStudent', function(req, res) {
            res.json(text);

        });
module.exports = router;
```

Now you can access it using this route  http://localhost:3000/students/getAllExcellenceStudent

Comment: I have tested it. Its working. Make sure what request you are sending GET/POST . Your request should be GET.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple errors in your code.

1 - `stud.excellence;` and `module.exports = function excellence() {` in this case you should use it as `var stud = require('./grades')();` 
 or

```
var stud = require('./grades'); 
var excellence = new stud();
```

2 - It wouldn't work, cos grades.js have no idea about variable `app`. So, as solution, you could pass it as argument:

```
    module.exports = function excellence(app) {
        app.get('/getAllExcellenceStudent', function(req, res) {
            res.json(text);

        })

    };

//index.js

var stud = require('./grades')(app);
```

You can, but this is totally wrong approach.
Mr. @bilalmetla gives correct answer, you should use express.Router.